# Difference between "Disk drives" and "IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers" in Windows Device Manager

Tags: windows, drivers, controller

They are all related to the hard disk storage. Why devide into two devices, who called who?

Comment: I would assume that you have misspelled (or misread) something: it is not named `Disk drivers` but `Disk drives` (only one r not two).

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I have edited my question.

Comment: I am sorry but isn't the answer obvious? A controller is the chip on your mainboard or PCI[e] card and it is at the one side of the SATA/IDE cable, the drive is the "thing" at the other side of the SATA/IDE cable.

Comment: You're basically asking "Difference between car engine and wheels. Why divide into two devices?"

Comment: @Robert I have understood your answer. But I still have confusion: every device has a software driver program in OS kernel, why we need two drivers to read/write bytes from disk? If "the drive is at the other side", why it's software driver is also in OS?

Comment: @Divlaker You're asking about three different things that make a whole: _Disk drives_ are HDDs/SSDs, _Drivers_ allow the OS to communicate with the hardware [controller], and _Controllers_ are the interface the drives connect to on the motherboard that controls how the hardware [HDDs/SSDs] is accessed.

Comment: @Divlaker Just a comparison: If your body would be a computer your corpus is the mainboard, your legs the "cables" and your feet the drives. How could your brain send a command to your feet if it doesn't have an in-brain representation of your feet? Same is with your computer. Hardware that is present but has no driver is inaccessible to the OS.

Comment: In fact, you need at least three drivers in most situations: Bus to storage controller (often PCIe), storage controller and then for the drives. Between controller and drives it’s usually another bus. Keep in mind that the drive could also be optical or a tape drive. Each requires different commands that are delivered over different buses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about three different things that make a whole:

- [Disk drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive): storage device hardware itself [HDDs/SSDs]
- [Disk controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_controller): motherboard interface [SATA/SAS] hardware connects to for CPU access
- [Device drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver): allows OS to communicate with the hardware controller